How do I store hashed passwords using Postgres for user authentication with Vaadin/Spring Security?
I'm working on an application that uses Vaadin (and thus Spring Boot and Spring Security), as well as a Postgres SQL database.  I've found several examples of how to use an @Repository interface as a source of users for authentication.  Aside from the fact most seem to be outdated, all seem to assume that passwords will be stored in cleartext in the database rather than hashed with salt.  Is there a way to do this with passwords stored properly?  Do I need to bite the bullet and recreate the JdbcUserDetailsManager from scratch?
I'm quite new to Vaadin, Spring Boot, and Spring Security.

there is an entire chapter on password storage in the spring security docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/authentication/password-storage.html they have full support for modern algorithms like Argon2 etc. And there are several code examples.

I'm upvoting to counteract the downvotes. Be nice to new users, people ;) OP has a genuine question and has tried to do their own research. Why the close votes?

Have a look at tis library:
https://github.com/Password4j/password4j
Basically you salt+hash the PW when the PW is set and then you store this in the DB.
Upon PW validation you redo the same salt+hash and then compare this "user-provided" value with the string in the database.
The Argon2 hash is the recommended hash method with proper minimal
configuration (while writing
this).
Or use a fallback where you see fit.
And store the pepper value somewhere outside the database for better
security.

why pull in a 3rd party library when spring security already has Argon2 built in? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/authentication/password-storage.html#authentication-password-storage-argon2

spring has no pepering for argon2, right?

Im sorry i dont understand the word ”pepering”?

@Toerktumlare https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_(cryptography)

ah "pepper", not "peper" i am fully aware of what peppering is, but it was written peper
